# Error reading kv Image source

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to display an image ('iphoto') pulled from another website using kv language. I am getting an error that the image file cannot be read, but yet I can copy the image address from the error and pull up the image in a browser with no problem. What am I doing wrong?

Info:

`Python 3.4`

`Kivy 1.9.1`

**Pertinent Python:** ('pet_photo' is the http address pulled from an xml SOAP response)

```
class ScrollerApp(App):
    for child in root.iter('pet_id'):
        iphoto = child.find('pet_photo').text
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('Scroller.kv')
        return TheBox()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.fullscreen = 'auto'
    ScrollerApp().run()
```

**Pertinent kv:**

```
<TheBox>:
    FloatLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            size: 810, 1080
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .21}         
            Image:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 790, 770
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .64} 
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                source: str(app.iphoto)
```

**The Error:**

> [ERROR             ] [Image       ] Error reading file http://sms.petpoint.com/sms/photos/615/ba451ef8-3dd5-428f-b437-cca6521024d0.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an AsyncImage. [AsyncImage Docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html#asynchronous-loading)

```
<TheBox>:
    FloatLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            size: 810, 1080
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .21}         
            AsyncImage:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 790, 770
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .64} 
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
                source: str(app.iphoto)
```